# NGINX - External Service Interaction via HTTP Header Injection

Tags: nginx, magento, nginx-reverse-proxy, varnish, nginx-location

I have received the "External Service Interaction via HTTP Header Injection" vulnerability report from security team upon scanning the customer facing domain:

Nginx is configured as proxy/LB server to route the requests to Magento Application hosted on different server. The routing is NGINX PROXY (LB-port-8080) --> Magento web server (NGINX-port-80)

Here is the nginx configuration on proxy server:

```html
server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;

  server_name magento-domain.com;
  server_name magento2-domain.com;

  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/magento.cer;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/magento.key;

  location / {
      proxy_pass http://10.00.00.00; <-- (IP of web server)
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 443;
      proxy_set_header host $host;

  location ~ (/wp|/wp/|/wordpress|/wordpress/|/admin|/admin/|/index.php/admin|/index.php/admin/|/urapidflowadmin|/index.php/urapidflowadmin|/index.php/webservice) {

      proxy_pass  http://10.00.00.00; <-- (IP of web server)
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 443;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_connect_timeout     3600;
      proxy_send_timeout        3600;
      proxy_read_timeout        3600;
      }

  }

}
```

and on default nginx cong I have this header for real_ip:

```
set_real_ip_from  0.0.0.0/0;
real_ip_header    X-Forwarded-For;
real_ip_recursive on;
```

As per the solution suggested by security team: Validate user inputs in all headers including Host header and X-Forwarded-Host header. The header value should be processed only if it appears on a approved/safe list of FQDNs.

What's the entry need to be added/removed from the nginx configuration specified.